# Sending whole object from one component to another in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a problem. I don't know how to send object from one component to another.

In first component *cinema.component.html* I have following function call:

```
<a title="Reserve" (click)="openReservationPage(repertoire)">Reserve</a>
```

In *cinema.component.ts* file, for that *.html* I have something like:

```
openReservationPage(repertoire: UpcomingRepertoire) {
    this.router.navigate(['/reserve', {repertoire: JSON.stringify(repertoire)}]);
}
```

My *app.routes.ts* file contains appropriate routing:

```
{ path: 'reserve', component: ReserveFormComponent }
```

How can I use this **repertoire** object in another page *reserve-form.component.ts* and *reserve-form.component.html* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer for the question in the title, i would said create a service to pass data between components.

Since its a router implementation you can pass the repertoire as a route parameter.

Follow these steps:

**1)Modify the route in app.routes.ts to take a param**

```
{ path: 'reserve/:repertoire', component: ReserveFormComponent }
```

**2)In cinema.component.ts pass the repertoire as param**

```
this.router.navigate(['/reserve',JSON.stringify(repertoire)]‌​);
```

**3)Extract the param in reserve-form.component.ts**

First of all you need to import

```
 import {ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
```

*Technique 1*

```
repertoire:any;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.repertoire = JSON.parse(activatedRoute.snapshot.params["repertoire"]);
  }
```

*Technique 2*

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Rx";

private subscription: Subscription;
repertoire:any;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.subscription = activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      (param: any) => this.repertoire = JSON.parse(param['repertoire'])
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { // here we unsubscribe to the observable
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**Further Explanation** :

*Technique 1* is adopted when you are sure that the param will be passed every time you navigate to the component.

*Technique 2* is a subscription to the observable once there a param published but don't forget to unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy()  component's life cycle method to prevent memory leak.

It is more preferable because some times there a scenario that a param is passed to a component after it was created where the snapshot method wouldn't capture and it more flexible with different scenario than the basic one in technique 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering this.
I use Technique 2 but now I am not redirected to /reserve component

Comment: Can you give me more info, you had an error or something ?

Comment: My URL now looks like
http://localhost:4200/reserve;repertoire=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
There was no error in browser console.
Basically I want to click on the Reserve link and call function

Comment: Can you try this please:

this.router.navigate(['/reserve', JSON.stringify(repertoire)]);
}

Comment: Edited:

this.router.navigate(['/reserve',JSON.stringify(repertoire)]);

Comment: I am redirected now :)
I have simple page reserve-form.component.html like this 
<div>    
    <h3><label>{{repertoire.id}}</label></h3>   
</div>

and I am not getting id printed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158757/discussion-between-farouk-el-kholy-and-aleksandar).

Answer (score 0):

The link below explains how you can do this. I've recently used this to create a messaging service. The example below, shows the code for a simple messaging service. It allows you to pass a number between components, just change the  to  I guess. You can also write out to local storage, but It seems services are more popular. Once you've got your head around them, they're easy to re-use.

Hope this helps

[Sharing Data Between Angular Components - Four Methods](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Message Service (PmMessageService)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject }    from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class PmMessageService
{

  private pillMenuIndexBS = new BehaviorSubject <number> (null);

  pillMenuIndex = this.pillMenuIndexBS.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setPillMenuIndex(index : number)
  {
    this.pillMenuIndexBS.next(index);
  }

}
```

Component consuming message service, setting a value

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PmMessageService } from '../pm-message-service/pm-message.service'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pm-configure',
  templateUrl: './pm-configure.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pm-configure.component.css']
})

export class PmConfigureComponent implements OnInit
{

  constructor (private messageService : PmMessageService) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.messageService.setPillMenuIndex(1);
  }

}
```

Component consuming and subscribing.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PmMessageService } from '../pm-message-service/pm-message.service'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './pm-bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pm-bs-navbar.component.css']
})

export class PmBsNavbarComponent implements OnInit
{

  tabActiveNumber;

  constructor (private messageService : PmMessageService) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.messageService.pillMenuIndex.subscribe(index => this.tabActiveNumber = index)
  }

}
```