# How to fire method or change the ui of root component with a button click of another component

Tags: angular

I have a `root component` and inside it, I load other `components` using `<router-outlet>`.

- Think I'm loding my `login component` first using `routing`.
- Then when user logged in to the system I `navigate` user like this -> `this.router.navigate(['/home']);`.
- I'm using a `service` to update the same value `Ex: loginstatus`. and according to that `value` I tried to change some `UI` elements in my `root` component. but it doesn't work. How can I do that. hope your help with this.

Comment: hope you have taken care of <base href="/"> in your index.html file. Please show what error do you get when you try to navigate?

Comment: yep @DeepakJha any solution for this.

Comment: what is the error exactly in the console?

Comment: it's not an error, I'm asking a way to do this process

Comment: tried this link? https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href

Comment: Do you need help around third point of yours? "I'm using a service to update the same value Ex: loginstatus. and according to that value I tried to change some UI elements in my root component. but it doesn't work. How can I do that. hope your help with this."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I'm understanding this correctly can't you do this with a messaging service? So, create a message service and then create subscriptions from your root component to it?

This explains it well [4 methods to share data](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

I also posted an example on this 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236416/sending-whole-object-from-one-component-to-another-in-angular-2/47236719#47236719)